# Boost libraries - build only what I need

Tags: c++, boost

I downloaded the Boost libraries and now I want to build only a few of the libraries. What would be the right command for this? Apparently the `build-type=complete` option gives me too much.
I am using Windows XP and want to use Bjam to compile Boost and MinGW to finally use it. At the moment I think I need the libraries Boost.filesystem, Boost.ProgramOptions and Boost.System.

Another question: Where do I put the header-only libraries?

Comment: This is only necessary and practical when you are building for embedded devices.  A quick count 13408 *.hpp and 264 *.h files.  Even for public headers there are over one thousand. In a normal system, many other packages may also depends on a different module in boost.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In [step 5.2.4](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#invoke-b2) of [Getting Started](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) you can instruct `b2` which libraries to build:

```
./b2 --with-program_options --with-filesystem --with-system
```

Alternatively, use `./b2 --show-libraries` to see a list of all libraries that are not header-only.

Following is an excerpt from the page:

> In particular, to limit the amount of time spent building, you may be interested in:
>
> - reviewing the list of library names with `--show-libraries`
> - limiting which libraries get built with the `--with-<library-name>` or `--without-<library-name>` options
> - choosing a specific build variant by adding release or debug to the command line.

**Note:** `b2` command depends upon boost version so use following commands as per your boost version(Also, in this case use `--with-libraries=<comma-seperated-library-names>` version instead of `--with-<library-name>`):

- `./configure` for `1.38.0` and earlier
- `./bootstrap.sh` for `1.39.0` onwards till `1.46.0`

Comment: OK, thank you. I did not read that, because I was only looking into the Windows description, but I think the command line options will be the same. Can you explain to me the difference between the options "--prefix" and "--build-dir"? Is the latter one only temporary? The first ist the install directory, right?

Comment: @Till `--prefix` is where you want boost to be installed. Typically `/usr` or `/usr/local` on Linux systems.

Comment: In a more recent Boost, replace `bootstrap` with `b2`.

Comment: @rustyx Also, it looks like the format is now --with-<libraryName> :  
    ./b2 --with-filesystem --with-system

Comment: I used `b2 --show-libraries` to try get the name of lib I want. But instead of doing that, b2 created a directory `C:\boost-build` and copied a bunch of files there (examples, b2.exe, bjam.exe, ...). Can't see any more info on that in Boost.Build doc. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 14):

These answers didn't work for me. On Windows, this worked for me:

```
b2.exe --with-LIBRARY
```

For example,

```
b2.exe --with-test
```

Comment: At least with current version (1.57) a double dash is required, e.g. `b2.exe --with-filesystem`

Comment: `b2.exe --with-test` complains "error: wrong library name 'test' in the --with-<library> option."

Answer (score 8):

The [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) utility is a tool for extracting subsets of Boost. It's useful for Boost authors who want to distribute their library separately from Boost, and for Boost users who want to distribute a subset of Boost with their application.

The current version of Boost (1.50.0) uses Boost.Build. The new workflow for building BCP is as follows:

From the root Boost directory, type:

```
bootstrap.bat
```

Then, once Boost.Build has been built, type:

```
b2 tools/bcp
```

To extract, for example `interprocess` only, you could use:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/interprocess #bcp needs this
$ bcp interprocess /tmp/interprocess
```

This copies interprocess and its dependencies to `/tmp/interprocess`.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. But I found a way to create the necessary files.

Steps to follow:

1. If you have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 then open the Microsoft Visual Studio command prompt (2010) in administrator mode.
2. First enter the code:

   ```
   bootstrap.bat
   ```
3. Then enter the following code to generate lib files:

   ```
   b2.exe link=static runtime-link=static --with-chrono --with-date_time --with-filesystem --with-program_options --with-system --toolset=msvc-10.0 define=BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x0500
   ```
4. Library files will be created in stage folder.

Answer (score 3):

My last build attempt for the Boost 1.55 libraries was a dissappointment. All attempts to build several libraries and only them has ended up with total mess in output.

BJam either tries to build everything or build only the requested, but in the "bin.v2/[long-random-path]" folders (library per directory) with crap in them which is a headache to copy only the link libraries to somethere else.

I have accidentally found the right way to build-and-collect only the libraries I want in one place without any other crap:

> bjam ... --with-[library1] --with-[library2] stage

- the "stage" option is required to build and collect libraries in one folder: /stage/lib
- the "--with-[library]" option is required to build only the library you want.

Comment: try install instead of stage

Comment: i don't want to install anything on the build machine, i only want to COPY it somethere else

Comment: that is exactly what install does - it copies out the headers and the linked files. copying it out manually from the staging directory is madness.

Comment: I don't know what exactly install does, but it can do anything else additionally to copy headers and linked files. And coping from staging directory exactly that i need.

Comment: any program can do anything - but I am telling you that in this case, install copies out header and binaries, and does nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

An additional note for anyone who sees the error message:
`"error: wrong library name '<name of library>' in the --with-<library> option."`.

If you try to be clever, as I did, and only extract the `boost` sub-directory of the download onto your system to minimise space, `b2` will not be able to find the source code and build options for those libraries that are not header-only. I.e. you need the `lib` sub-directory too (and `tools`).