# How do I build boost 1.70.0 without enabling exceptions?

Tags: c++, boost, build

I have upgraded to Boost 1.70.0, and built the binaries using bootstrap and b2, and inserted this into our codebase, but unfortunately I'm getting plenty of linker errors about the absence of one function: boost::throw_exception(class stdext::exception const &).

I've spotted BOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE and BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS as preprocessor tests in the source, but I don't know how to amend the build configuration to ensure the linker doesn't look for this symbol. I've tried defining each of these symbols at the top of each source file, to no avail, so I imagine building the boost binaries introduced this dependency.

This hasn't been a problem before, so I suspect the prior versions were built in a cunning way to disable exception use. However, nobody in the studio can recall this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to build using a custom "b2" command. For example, to build the math library under linux, without exceptions. Obviously if you are building under MSVC you need to use MS-style flags.
Not all libraries build binaries, so you need to add these to your own build as well. Also, bare in mind not all libraries support no-exceptions.

```
./b2 cxxflags="-fno-exceptions -DBOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS" --with-system
```

to see which libraries are built

```
./b2 --show-libraries
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714289/boost-libraries-build-only-what-i-need) for more generic advice for custom building problems.