# How to install and use Boost.Program_options library?

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to build the following package:
https://github.com/kahypar/kahypar

In the requirement section, it asks for  [Boost.Program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options.html) and I don't really know what that is and how I should deal with that. I appreciate that if you help me with that.
I am using a macOS and I already installed boost by using:

```
brew install boost
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.program_options

Comment: Define `doesn't work`. Please provide a [mre] with any error messages from the compiler

Answer (score 2):

> ### NOTICE
>
> Because some people don't seem to realize, the manual instructions apply 100% for macOS (except for how to get the build-essentials, but apparently OP already has them)
>
> However, I cannot demo on macOS because I don't own a Mac. Sorry

The normal way is to install boost following either your distro or manually:

### Distro

For example Ubuntu 20.04

```
apt -qq update
apt -qqyy install build-essential libboost-all-dev cmake git


git clone --recurse-submodules  https://github.com/kahypar/kahypar
cmake -B build kahypar/
cmake --build build -j5
```

Make some coffee. Profit.

### Manual Build

This uses [Boost libraries - build only what I need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714289/boost-libraries-build-only-what-i-need) to save on time:

```
apt -qqyy install build-essential cmake git python3-dev wget
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.75.0/source/boost_1_75_0.tar.bz2
tar xf boost_1_75_0.tar.bz2
(cd boost_1_75_0; ./bootstrap.sh; ./b2 --with-program_options)

git clone --recurse-submodules  https://github.com/kahypar/kahypar
BOOST_ROOT="$PWD/boost_1_75_0" cmake -B build kahypar/
cmake --build build -j5
```

### LIVE DEMO

Screencasts of

- [using distro package](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/1554050e-d611-4570-bdaa-a3bda47fac2a/using-distro-package.mp4) and
- [using manual build](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/37631b95-9af9-4144-b9c7-bb98591c3db1/using-manual-build.mp4).

Of course you might just get away with pointing `BOOST_ROOT` at wherever the brew install resides, but I can't help you with that because I can't test it. In all likelihood you would need to set include/link paths separately.

Comment: Added a notice just in case people didn't realize you can the manual approach exactly on macOS.

Comment: Fixed the screencast vids (had them swapped initially)

Comment: If you forget the (helpfully highlighted) `all` in the package name `libboost-all-dev`, like I did, and `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev` , then you get the headers only but not the libraries.